# Handle single quote in SqlParameter in EXEC sp_setapprole?

Tags: c#, winforms, sqlcommand, sqlparameter

I have a method that executes a SqlCommand and returns the result to a winforms application.
My method is this:

```
public bool ApplyRoles(string roleApp, string roleAppPassword)
{
     Command = new SqlCommand("EXEC sp_setapprole @roleApp, @rolePassword", Connection);
     AssignParam("roleApp", roleApp, SqlDbType.VarChar);
     AssignParam("rolePassword", roleAppPassword, SqlDbType.VarChar);
     bool ret = Command.ExecuteNonQuery() == -1;
     return ret;
}
```

and the `AssignParam` method is this:

```
public void AssignParam(string name, object value, SqlDbType type)
{
    var parameter = new SqlParameter(name, type)
    {
         Value = value ?? DBNull.Value
    };
    Command.Parameters.Add(parameter);
}
```

Now, this `ApplyRoles` method throws the exception: `Application roles can only be activated at the ad hoc level.` but if i change the `ApplyRoles` to this:

```
public bool ApplyRoles(string roleApp, string roleAppPassword)
{
   Command = new SqlCommand(string.Format("EXEC sp_setapprole '{0}', '{1}'", roleApp, roleAppPassword), Connection);
   bool ret = Command.ExecuteNonQuery() == -1;
   return ret;
}
```

The method works fine.. so i'm guessing that the problem is in the `AssignParam` method.
What is the problem? I don't want to use the "working" method because i could have sql injection on it.

Comment: I don't see the error but why aren't you using the normal way of invoking a proc? Leave out the `EXEC` stuff.

Comment: You mean `new SqlCommand("sp_setapprole", Connection)`? but how .NET identify the `@roleApp` and `@rolePassword` when i set the `AssignParam` method?

Comment: you have to set the `CommandType.StoredProcedure`. See my answer below to what your root problem was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[sp_setapprole](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188908.aspx) uses the parameter names `@rolename` and `@password`. You have to use those parameter names if you are passing the parameter names into the a SqlCommand` instance. It was working for you in your second example because you were passing only the parameter values in the correct order that the stored proc was expecting them.

Since you're executing a stored procedure, use `CommandType.StoredProcedure`

Also put the '@' character in front of your parameter names.

```
Command = new SqlCommand("sp_setapprole", Connection);
Command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
Command.Parameters.AddWithValue( @rolename, roleApp);
Command.Parameters.AddWithValue( @password, rolePassword);
bool ret = Command.ExecuteNonQuery() == -1;
     return ret;
```

Comment: The '@' character is necessary? because i leave with out the char and works too.

Comment: Not necessary, but I like using it because it is more readable.